# Angular4 connecting weather API

Tags: angular

I'm trying to teach myself Angular4 while making a Weather app. I'm having trouble getting the API to connect. I've tried following allowing with the following resources.

https://medium.com/craft-academy/connecting-an-api-to-an-angular-4-front-end-application-e0fc9ea33202

https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-4-3-httpclient-accessing-rest-web-services-with-angular-2305b8fd654b

I haven't been able to get an object to appear in the console as in the examples. I'm not getting any errors in the terminal or console. I commented out the other way I tried to get this to work and removed apikey for the example. Here is my app.component.ts. Other than this I imported httpclientmodule in my app.module.ts. I'm a beginner and this is my first time posting so I'm sorry if I'm doing it wrong.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
    styleUrls: [ "./app.component.css" ]
})
export class AppComponent {
    name = "Angular 4 Weather App";
    apiKey = "";
    private apiUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=london&APPID=" + this.apiKey;
    data: any = {};

    constructor (private http: HttpClient) {
//         this.getWeather();
//         this.getWeatherData();
    }

//     getWeather() {
//       return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
//         .map((res: Response) => res.json())
//     }
//     getWeatherData() {
//       this.getWeather().subscribe(data => {
//         console.log(data);
//         this.data = data;
//       })
//     }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.http.get(this.apiUrl).subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Open the developer tools panel in Chrome (presss F12) and go to the Network tab. Refresh your app to re-trigger the request and see what is the actual response from the server. It could be that you're getting an error from the API. The code looks good.

Comment: I believe you can't just simply make a function called `ngOnInit` and have the framework call it. Your class needs to implement `OnInit`. See the peek a boo component here: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks. Easiest thing to do is set a debugger or console.log at the beginning of the `ngOnInit` function to ensure it's even being run. Once you get this working spend some time looking at the full list of hooks on that page to see which one you want to use for your use case.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the network tab. The apiUrl has a status of 200. Also, tried console.log at beginning of ngOnInit with OnInit added to the class with no luck. However, doing an alert instead of console.log worked both with/without OnInit added. I'm not sure if that's normal.

Answer (score 1):

Don't apologize for being new, you'll learn quick!

What your going to want to do is create a TypeScript Service for making the call to the weather API in order to get the data back. You'll then call this from whatever component you have (currently AppComponent). You can separate your logic and server calls better this way.

When you execute the service setup, try something like this.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

@Injectable()
export class WeatherService {

    $result: Observable<any>;
    weather: any;

    loadWeather() {  
        $result = this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
            .map(response => { return response["data"] });
            .share();
    }

    this.$result.subscribe(weather => {
        this.weather = weather;
    });

    return this.$result;
}
```

FYI, mapping the response back from the server may differ depending on the response you get back.

From here you can reference the $result observable inside of your TS service and grab any data out of it and throw it into the weather object. You won't need to statically define any objects to hold the data, you'll now be able to grab whatever is in the object whether or not it changes.

I highly recommend going through this tutorial if you haven't, it helped me a lot: https://angular.io/tutorial

Your AppComponent can then call the TS service, specifically that method, to get the data back. You can then subscribe to it and it will do your logic whenever it receives the data back.

AppComponent:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        public weatherService: WeatherService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.weatherService.loadWeather().subscribe(weather => {
             ...Do Logic Here....
             todaysTemp = weather.todaysTemp;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried following https://angular.io/guide/http to set up a service but was getting some errors. I figured it would be the best way to do it because I have a weather and search component that would both need access. I guess I started doing it in the app component to see if I could get data from the API first and also that was how the initial links I provided had it set up. I should probably go through that tutorial before I try anything else. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Hope that helped. That tutorial helped me out a ton, hopefully you find it useful as well!